# Filter table data using 2 column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, datatable

I created a table with 5 columns. From that table Brand and Category columns are using to filter PhoneStore table data.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Brand          |     Category     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|Apple, Huawei        |    6s, P30       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I earlier used to filter only using Brand column so I declare a variable like below.

```
declare @BRAND varchar(max)
set @BRAND =(select BRAND from [dbo].[PhoneDetails] where Flag='INSERTED')
```

Then I filter the other table data like below.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[PhoneStore] WHERE Brand IN ( SELECT Brand FROM dbo.SplitString(@BRAND,','))
```

But now I want to filter the PhoneStore table where brand equals Apple and Category equals 6s. There can be multiple Brands and Categories but number of brands and categories are same because Apple brand's category is 6s. Like above query I want to filter for all Brands and Categories. In above scenario it is ((Brand = 'Apple' and Category = '6s') or (Brand = 'Huawei' and Category = 'P30')).

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The problem is you're storing delimited data in your table. Don't. Fix the design, fix the problem. Normalise your data.

Comment: You could do that using `CROSS APPLY`, but ... @Larnu gives you the right and proper way.